# Combinatorial identity from squaring the binomial expansion

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, combinatorial-proofs

It is trivial to obtain, from squaring the binomial expansion of $(1+t)^{1/2}$ and comparing coefficients, that
$$\tag1
\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{1/2}k\binom{1/2}{m-k}=0,\qquad m\geq2.
$$
This can be rewritten as
$$\tag2
\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}\frac{(2k-2)!(2(m-k)-2)!}{k!(k-1)!(m-k)!(m-k-1)!}=\frac{(2m-2)!}{m!(m-1)!},\qquad m\geq2.
$$

I wonder if there is a direct proof of these equalities, in either version.

Comment: i think maybe snake-oil method can be used

Comment: Yes, that's basically the method I mention in my first sentence.

Comment: How is the first equation equivalent to the second equation?

Comment: @AlanAbraham: the left-hand side in $(2)$ is the sum from $1$ to $m-1$ in $(1)$, and the right hand side is minus the sum of the terms $k=0$ and $k=m$ in $(1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation (2) can be rewritten as $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} C_{k-1}C_{m-k-1} = C_{m-1},$$ where $C_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ Catalan number. Any introductory article on Catalan numbers should contain one or more counting proofs of that identity.